How to close an account without coding?
Guys so I don't know coding....Some days ago I sent one token and saw that it took 0.002sol... in solscan it showed me 'create account with deposit of 0.002sol'. But then after some research I got to know that to send tokens to a new address(in which we never have sent that same token) we have to pay 0.002sol.. if we want to close it then the account we are sending has to redeem that 0.002sol... but first my question is that suppose someone sent me a token(from wallet not owned by me)...he makes an account and deposited 0.002sol, then I recived the token and want to close that account(by claiming that 0.002sol), then how can I do so without coding...and is it possible to do that without paying gas? And my second question is that does this same principle also happen in memecoin trading?
Thanks

I’m voting to close this question because this site is for developer q&a

you can burn the tokens to get your sol back but burning means you'll lose those tokens, you can burn directly from phantom wallet
